# Fastlane : Supply : Is there a way to upload multiple APKs using same lane?

Tags: android, fastlane

**Is there a way to upload multiple APKs using the same lane?**

I have over 100 apps to upload to playstore. All of them are declared as different flavours with different package names, in gradle file. I was able to generate signed APKs of all the flavours by running the gradle task 'assemble', build type: Release.

Is there a way to upload all those generated APKs to playstore using a single lane. I tried using the following supply command. But its asking me the package name when running.

```
supply(
track: 'rollout',
skip_upload_screenshots: 'true',
skip_upload_apk: 'false')
```

As per my understanding, if I mention package name, then it will upload only that specific APK to playstore. My requirement is to upload all of the generated APKs to playstore using a single Supply script. Is it possible? Is there any way to achieve my goal with minimum lines of code?